# Disable Background Audio

Tags: codenameone

I created the following code to play audio in my app. How can I stop the playback when the app is minimized? As of now, the audio will continue to play until the app is " destroyed "

```
backgroundMusicStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/backgroundMusic.mp3");

try {   
    backgroundMusic = MediaManager.createMedia(backgroundMusicStream, "audio/mp3", onComplete);
    backgroundMusic.setVolume(35);
    backgroundMusic.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `stop()` method in the main class to stop "in progress" elements and invoke this code. You can debug this in the simulator using the `Pause`/`Resume` menu options.

BTW I would recommend using `Log.e(exception)` instead of `printStackTrace()`.